# Obtain 'post' form URL using .cgi file

Tags: python, forms, post, cgi

File name: `http://localhost/PostForm.html`

```
<form method ="post" action="Information.cgi">
<table>
<tr><td>New date: </td><td> <input type ="date" name="DateNew" /></td></tr><br> 
<tr><td>Old date: </td><td> <input type ="date" name="OldDate" /></td></tr><br> 
</table>
<input type="submit" name = "submitname" value="Add Entry" />
</form>
```

Is there any way in which I can obtain the file name, which the post form is located on, from the .cgi python file? 
I want to obtain the file name  `http://localhost/PostForm.html` in the Information.cgi Python file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get that information, but not in a completely secure way. Browsers insert a header, `Referer:` which names the previous page.

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to grab the referrer info within Information.cgi using an Environmental Variable:

```
$ReferringPage = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};
```

However, that's unreliable. Some users change browser settings to prevent sending referrer info amongst other possible situations where it might not pass.

You could also hard-code something in the referring page's form HTML that lets you know which page sent the referral:

```
<input type="hidden" name="wherefrom" value="Somepage.html">
```

Then, in your Information.cgi script, just grab that value and do whatever with it:

```
use CGI;
$in = new CGI;
$WhichPage = $in->{'wherefrom'};
```

This could be bypassed by the user or it might not work depending on your setup, but could work in some situations.